# how get table data and post data for Navistion Database in phoneGap

Tags: mysql, sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, navision

We are very struggled about getting and posting table data for Navistion Database.We need getting data for Navistion DB to our local(sqlLit) DataBase and posting data SqlLit Db to Navistion DB.In PHoneGap
We are goggled.But no luck.So Please give any documentation and link .Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap/Cordova can work with other databases when you use middleware on your server to respond to it. So for example, your server (with the Navistion DB) could use PHP or ColdFusion to respond to Ajax requests from your app. It would handle taking the request, querying the db, and converting the response to JSON. There is no documentation link for this as it is too abstract of a question really.

Comment: some one developed Nav Web Services and some give to url to me We are struggled about How can I insert a json object into a sqlite table in javascript, phonegap (cordova) Please help me

Comment: Well this question is completely separate from what you asked above. I'd suggest a new SO post.

Comment: sorry i am confounded to posting actually what we  need is 1)How can I insert a json object into a sqlite table in javascript, phonegap (cordova)
        2)server-based login with PhoneGap  but second one we have your websit http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap# so Please give me any idea bout my first problem

Comment: You are asking _multiple_ questions now, neither of which match the *original* question. I suggest asking *new* questions, one each.

Comment: Please look this my question

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Raymond - the question is too general to give any kind of recommendation. Maybe if you could elaborate it a bit - at least outline the task you need to solve, it would be easier to suggest something.
Anyway, I presume, you don't want to insert data into the Navision DB directly, but need an interface to Nav functionality. My first idea would be to look at Web services. Some documentation is available on msdn: [Web services in Nav](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338978(v=nav.71).aspx). You can expose Nav objects (Codeunits, Pages and Queries) through a web service and call it from PhoneGap.

Comment: some one developed Nav Web Services and some give to url to me We are struggled about How can I insert a json object into a sqlite table in javascript, phonegap (cordova) .Please help me